# qmake problem with image converter on 22.04

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to install *"lcd-image-converter"* onto my Ubuntu 22.04 only laptop but I cannot get *qmake* to work. Initially I kept getting the warning

> qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No
> such file or directory

I tried everything I could find to fix this issue, such as re-installing *qt4-qmake and libqt4-dev but all to no avail. Finally I installed *qt5-qmake* with `sudo apt-get install -y qt5-qmake` Typing *qmake --version* now gives:

> QMake version 3.1 Using Qt version 5.15.3 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Now when I cd into the *"lcd-image-converter"* directory and run *qmake* I get the warning:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui xml xmlpatterns
> network widgets qml

I want a converter to convert an image into a "C" source format for an Arduino embedded application.  If someone could help me install lcd-image-converter or recomment another application which can convert an image into a "C" source format  I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try *ImageMagick* and use its `convert` or `mogrify` commands. *ImageMagick* is the swiss army knife of image conversion tools.

Not sure what target image format you need; it sounds a lot like old XPM (which is essentially a C header file with a hexdump).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04:

```
git clone https://github.com/riuson/lcd-image-converter.git
cd lcd-image-converter/
git checkout develop

sudo apt install qtcreator qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake cmake
sudo apt install build-essential mesa-common-dev
sudo apt install libqt5svg5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev

qmake
make -j 20
./release/linux/output/lcd-image-converter
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls5qb.png)